# Filter a list to only leave objects that occur once

Tags: python, list, filter

I would like to filter this list,

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

to only leave

```
[0]
```

I'm struggling to do it in a 'pythonic' way. Is it possible without nested loops?

Comment: @Scott - Read the title.

Comment: @Markus - Yes, that helps! I think I must be going blind. I'm going to delete my original comment before everyone else thinks I'm an idiot too! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's another dictionary oriented way:

```
l = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
d = {}
for i in l: d[i] = i in d

[k for k in d if not d[k]]  # unordered, loop over the dictionary
[k for k in l if not d[k]]  # ordered, loop over the original list
```

Comment: +1 Really nice, it collects not a bit more information than you need to solve the task. You can get rid of the `.keys()` though.

Comment: Yes, .keys() is entirely optional, but slightly more readable IMO.

Comment: nice thinking 'cause it doesn't have unnecessary info like Alex's does, though it's essentially the same concept, and it won't work on items which aren't hashable.

Comment: @mhawke: no it isn't. It is much slower because `d.keys()` in Python 2 produces a new list object each time you call it. In Python 3 it creates a new dictionary view each time. Use `k in d`, *always*. And `dict.has_key` has been deprecated in favour of `key in dict`. And if you looped over `l` instead of `d` you get to maintain order just like Alex's version does. Together, that makes `for i in l: d[i] = i in d` and `[k for k in l if not d[k]]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks for the suggestions that would improve this ancient answer.

Answer (score 12):

You'll need two loops (or equivalently a loop and a listcomp, like below), but not nested ones:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for x in L: d[x] += 1
L[:] = [x for x in L if d[x] == 1]
```

This solution assumes that the list items are *hashable*, that is, that they're usable as indices into dicts, members of sets, etc.

The OP indicates they care about object IDENTITY and not VALUE (so for example two sublists both worth `[1,2,3` which are equal but may not be identical would not be considered duplicates). If that's indeed the case then this code is usable, just replace `d[x]` with `d[id(x)]` in both occurrences and it will work for ANY types of objects in list L.

Mutable objects (lists, dicts, sets, ...) are typically not hashable and therefore cannot be used in such ways. User-defined objects are by default hashable (with `hash(x) == id(x)`) unless their class defines comparison special methods (`__eq__`, `__cmp__`, ...) in which case they're hashable if and only if their class also defines a `__hash__` method.

If list L's items are not hashable, but *are* comparable for inequality (and therefore sortable), and you don't care about their order within the list, you can perform the task in time `O(N log N)` by first sorting the list and then applying `itertools.groupby` (almost but not quite in the way another answer suggested).

Other approaches, of gradually decreasing perfomance and increasing generality, can deal with unhashable sortables when you DO care about the list's original order (make a sorted copy and in a second loop check out repetitions on it with the help of `bisect` -- also O(N log N) but a tad slower), and with objects whose only applicable property is that they're comparable for equality (no way to avoid the dreaded O(N**2) performance in that maximally general case).

If the OP can clarify which case applies to his specific problem I'll be glad to help (and in particular, if the objects in his are ARE hashable, the code I've already given above should suffice;-).

Comment: No I don't need to hash I think it's just the duplication of objects that I wanted to remove. (I'm still thinking in C but what I wanted to say above was that the pointers to the objects will be the same so there is no need to hash -- is that valid in Python land?)

Comment: Why did you write "L[:] = list(set(L))" instead of the more obvious (to me) "L = list(set(L))"?  They seem to do the same thing when I try them in the interpreter.  Is there some nuance I'm missing?  Thanks!

Comment: The second solution doesn't seem to do the right thing: it removes duplicates, but the problem was to remove all items that are duplicated.

Comment: @samtregar, rebinding just the name sometimes works just as well as rebinding the contents, sometimes it doesn't (because there are other outstanding references to the original list object beyond its original name -- e.g that's the case for function arguments), why risk it?

Comment: Love collections.defaultdict. I need to write a bot that will answer all python questions with defaultdict.

Comment: This could be updated to use `collections.Counter()` instead: `d = Counter(L)` then `L[:] = [x for x in L if d[x] == 1]`.

Answer (score 11):

```
[x for x in the_list if the_list.count(x)==1]
```

Though that's still a nested loop behind the scenes.

Comment: I think I prefer Alex's solution as it only iterates through the list twice, your solution is n^2.

Comment: WOW. I really need to go away a read about list comprehension! I'm still trying to figure out exactly what is happening above. But thanks very much sepp and Alex.

Comment: @boyfarrell: you can read that as "Go through all x in the_list and select those where `the_list.count(x)==1`, i.e. those that appear only once"

Comment: Yep, and my approach boils down to exactly the same, except that I do a single pass beforehand to compute how many times each object appears (so the overall approach is O(N)) instead of a counting pass _per item_ (which makes this approach overall O(N**2)).

Comment: Alex's solution may be faster, but this is more elegant I think. ;-)

Comment: I'm not going to vote sepp2k's solution down, but it is not the best solution. Alex's use of defaultdict and a list comprehension to filter is exactly right. It *is* elegant.

Comment: @Markus: quadratic behaviour is not really all that elegant.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> l = [0,1,1,2,2]
>>> [x for x in l if l.count(x) is 1]
[0]
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `is` over `==`? I know 1 is a small enough number for this to work, but is `is` actually faster when comparing integers?

Comment: You shouldn't use `is` with numbers, it only works because cpython optimizes some often used constants ( like small (<255) ints, 1.0, 0.0, empty tuples/sets, etc) and treats them as singletons ... but that is not part of the python *language*.

Comment: Do **not** use `is` when testing for value equality. This solution is a O(N**2) complexity approach as `list.count()` does a full scan of the list each time you call it, and you call it N times.

Answer (score 4):

In the same spirit as Alex's solution you can use a [Counter](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/)/multiset (built in 2.7, recipe compatible from 2.5 and above) to do the same thing:

```
In [1]: from counter import Counter

In [2]: L = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

In [3]: multiset = Counter(L)

In [4]: [x for x in L if multiset[x] == 1]
Out[4]: [0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = [0,1,2,1,2]
def justonce( l ):
    once = set()
    more = set()
    for x in l:
        if x not in more:
            if x in once:
                more.add(x)
                once.remove( x )
            else:
                once.add( x )
    return once

print justonce( l )
```

Comment: Converting back to a list would be nice.

Comment: This doesn't preserve order like Alex's does.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> l = [0,1,1,2,2]
>>> [x for x in l if l.count(x) == 1]
[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the actual timings are kind of interesting:

Alex' answer:

```
python -m timeit -s "l = range(1,1000,2) + range(1,1000,3); import collections" "d = collections.defaultdict(int)" "for x in l: d[x] += 1" "l[:] = [x for x in l if d[x] == 1]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 370 usec per loop
```

Mine:

```
python -m timeit -s "l = range(1,1000,2) + range(1,1000,3)" "once = set()" "more = set()" "for x in l:" " if x not in more:" "  if x in once:" "   more.add(x)" "   once.remove( x )" "  else:" "   once.add( x )"
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 usec per loop
```

sepp2k's O(n**2) version, to demonstrate why compexity matters ;-)

```
python -m timeit -s "l = range(1,1000,2) + range(1,1000,3)" "[x for x in l if l.count(x)==1]"
100 loops, best of 3: 16 msec per loop
```

Roberto's + sorted:

```
python -m timeit -s "l = range(1,1000,2) + range(1,1000,3); import itertools" "[elem[0] for elem in itertools.groupby(sorted(l)) if elem[1].next()== 0]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 316 usec per loop
```

mhawke's:

```
python -m timeit -s "l = range(1,1000,2) + range(1,1000,3)" "d = {}" "for i in l: d[i] = d.has_key(i)" "[k for k in d.keys() if not d[k]]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 251 usec per loop
```

I like the last, clever and fast ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question came up on a coding problem. My solution isn't the most elegant but is my first self-conjured solution so wanted to share!

```
testlist = [2,4,6,8,10,2,6,10]

def unique_elements(testlist):
    final_list = []
    for x in testlist:
        if testlist.count(x)==1:
            final_list.append(x)
        else:
            pass
    print(final_list)

unique_elements(testlist)
```